# Problem opening Siemens Teamcenter Active workspace via JCEF via IBM Rhapsody 8.4. Opening it from Rhapsody only gives a white screen

Tags: java, swing, rhapsody

But if we isolate the code and run the code separately(from eclipse and not Rhapsody) it renders perfectly. In Task manager > Details tab, we can see that 5 jcef_helper threads are created.

We're using Swing (JFrame etc) in the integration code to launch it from Rhapsody.

What might be the reason its not opening from Rhapsody?
In Rhapsody the jcef_helper threads are not created in the first place.

We're using JCEF in both the cases.

Comment: There's too little information in the question to be able to answer it. However, a swing GUI can be frozen if a time consuming task is running on the event thread - the single thread that paint the GUI.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer I've added some details about threads creation. Please check out